# Inherited form problem

Tags: winforms, inheritance

i have a windows form that inherites from another windows form in the same project,
the problem is when i click a button in the inherited form the eventhandler fires twice
performing the event in the parent form and then performs the event in the inherited form
.
any suggestions?

http://www.metacafe.com/watch/852308/inheritied_forms_c/
 in this video u will see what am doing exactly and the problem am facing is in the end of this video .. u will see exactly what i mean –

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? That only the event in the inherited fires?

Comment: http://www.metacafe.com/watch/852308/inheritied_forms_c/ 
in this video u will see what am doing exactly and the problem am facing is in the end of this video .. u will see exactly what i mean

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it's supposed to work. You have two event handlers, both are executed. I would suggest the following:

In the parent form, add a method

```
Protected Overridable Sub OnOKButtonClick()
    MsgBox("Parent Form OK Button Clicked")
End Sub
```

which you call from the button's click event. In the inherited form, remove the button click event handler, and override the OnButtonClick method

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnOKButtonClick()
    MsgBox("Inherited Form OK Button Clicked")
End Sub
```

This should accomplish what you are after.